# mongodb - how to use $project with $or

Tags: mongodb

I have a following collection:

```
_id,
one,
two,
messages: [{
    sender
    seen
}]
```

and I need to get count for 'messages' in each collection, where `(one=1 AND sender IS NOT 1) OR (two=1 AND sender IS NOT 1)`

```
'$or': [
    { 'one': 1, 'messages.sender': {$ne: 1},
    { 'two': 1, 'messages.sender': {$ne: 1}
]
```

edit

When I try to `$project` with `$or`, returns me nothing

```
Conversation.aggregate([
    {
        '$or': [
            { 'one': 1, 'messages.sender': {$ne: 1},
            { 'two': 1, 'messages.sender': {$ne: 1}
        ]
    },
    {

        $project: {
            count: { $size:"$messages" }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, c) {
    res.json(c);
});
```

I'm really stuck with this and have no clue how to get the results.

Thanks for help

Comment: Actually `{ "$match": { "messages.sender": { "$ne": 1 }, "$or": [{ "one": 1 },{ "two": 1 }] } }` writes a little more efficiently. But what exactly is the problem? Are you just trying to get the total size of the messages array for each document? Or messages matching certain criteria or what exactly. Does the query even work? We don't know because you don't actually show a real document, nor do you really clearly explain what should happen. If you could clear these things up, then it's easier to respond with an answer to your problem. Right now is not clear what you want or what is wrong.

Comment: I was clearly wrote `and I need to get count for 'messages' in each collection, where (one=1 AND sender IS NOT 1) OR (two=1 AND sender IS NOT 1)`.

Comment: Problem is that when i try use condition inside aggregate, returns me noting. So, I need all messages count in each collection where `'one': 1, 'messages.sender': {$ne: 1} or 'two': 1, 'messages.sender': {$ne: 1}`. I hope to understand now

Comment: It's not clear at all, and the question title asks for something that does not exist ( you don't `$project` with `$or` ), therefore I'm "very nicely" asking you to spend a few minutes making your question **clearer**. When asking for "help" you really need to express less attitude if your expectation is "help". You're just repeating the same thing over and over. the `'one'` field field in your "structure" is NOT part of the messages array. So we don't know if you mean count the messages, count the documents or what it really is.

Comment: Dude. Look at the very first comment. The first aggregation stage is `$match`

Answer (score 0):

You can use $cond operator in 2.6 version as a work around solution.

Assuming that we have the next collection :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad469bb18a5a3164402d279"), 
    "Show" : true, 
    "Name" : "Alamir"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad469c318a5a3164402d27a"), 
    "Show" : false, 
    "Name" : "Alamir"
}
```

and we want to project the result based on 'Show' filed as (If show == true then show the field , else hide the filed from the result set )

So the query will be :

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { $project : 
      { Name : 1 , 
        Show : 
      { 
        $cond : { if : { $eq : ["$Show" , true] } , then : "$Show" , else : "" } 
      }
      }}])
```

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking, Took them forever to get to it, but they were in fact asking what I suspected they were and essentially answered in comment.